# Masonry in Rails - Boxes are sometimes not aligned on refresh

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

The page in which I'm having the issue with is on: http://forkfox.com/tours

If you refresh the page enough times, usually on the second time or even of the first page load, you'll see that some of the boxes are going on top of each other.

The JS

```
var container = document.querySelector('#alltours');
var msnry = new Masonry( alltours, {
  // options
  itemSelector: '.box',
});
```

Let me know if you need any other information to help solve this.

Thanks!

EDIT 1: I've added imagesLoaded as it was suggested below but I appear to still be having the same issue.

```
// or with jQuery
// initialize Masonry
var $container = $('#alltours').masonry();
// layout Masonry again after all images have loaded
$container.imagesLoaded( function() {
  $container.masonry();
});
```

Comment: What browser are you on? I'm not seeing any issue using edge FF/Chrome on OSX.

Comment: @zeantsoi It appears that Chrome is causing the issue. I don't see issues on Firefox. A different computer also using Chrome is seeing the same results.

Comment: Just tried it on Firefox and the same issue. Weird that it only appears sometimes.

Comment: UPDATE: Meh nevermind, wasn't reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could probably be an issue with Chrome's aggressive caching. You might want to take a look at https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded.

```
imagesLoaded( document.querySelector('#alltours'), function( instance ) {
  // Call Masonry here...
});
```

But since you're already using jQuery:

```
$('#alltours').imagesLoaded( function() {
  // Call Masonry here...
});
```

Let me know it that helps.

Comment: That didn't seem to work. I'm convinced that it has nothing to do with Chrome since the issue appears to occur in all browsers.

Comment: Perhaps I'm writing the jQuery Masonry wrong. Could you give me an example?

Comment: It's hard to tell given your minified JS file, but did you add imagesloaded to the asset pipeline? Calling imagesLoaded(...) results in "ReferenceError: imagesLoaded is not defined"

Answer (score 2):

You've got this error on the page:
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'imagesLoaded'

First thing to do is actually include imagesLoaded in your scripts to load:
http://desandro.github.io/imagesloaded/

Download and include it using a  tag. It stopped being included as part of Masonry in one of the more recent releases. Additionally, I would remove the floating from your .box div and allow Masonry to control positioning. Since masonry will absolute position your float isn't having any effect.

.thumbnail a { 
give that a display type of block. Could be leading to a miscalculated height.

Comment: I fixed the issue with Uncaught TypeError. Unfortunately that didn't solve the issue. I also removed the float and added the display:block.

Comment: I lied. Actually the issue still exists even though it's added in the asset pipeline.

Comment: I lied again. One of the issues (along with not including it within the application.js) was the order in which it was being called. Here's what I did. '//= require jquery
//= require masonry.pkgd.min.js
//= require imagesloaded.pkgd.js
//= require box.js'